# Echo user info on another users profile page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to make a function in the CodeIgniter framework so users can click on product detail page, and see which user uploaded that certain product and they must be able to click on the product owner to go to his profile page.

Now, I am already able to echo owner information of the product owner on the details page. But the link to the owner profile page is not working some reason and the name isn't echoed anymore since I tried to make it a link.

This is my product details page (details.php) foreach loop function where I'm trying to echo the username of the owner of a product and link it to their profile page:

```
<?php include_once ('templates/header.php'); ?>
<div class="container">
    <h3>Email van de eigenaar:</h4>
        <?php
        foreach ($userdetail_list as $row) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:24px;">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto']; ?>" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h1> <div class="product_naam"> <?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?>  </div> </h1>
            <h3>Over dit cadeau</h3>
            <div class="product_beschrijving"><?php echo $product['product_beschrijving']; ?> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Cadeauaanvragen"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cadeau aanvragen</button></a>
            <div class="aangeboden_door">   Aangeboden door:    <?php
            foreach ($userdetail_list as $row) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'User/profiel_user?id=' . $row['user_id'] ?>"><?= $row['username']; ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="container">
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; kadokado 2017, Inc.</p>
    </footer>
    <hr>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php include_once ('templates/footer.php'); ?>
```

When I load this view file I do see the echoeod email but not the username? And there is also no link to the users profile page..

Here is my controller file (User.php):

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('profile', $data);
    }
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if ($_SESSION['user_logged'] == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "Please login first to view this page!! ");
            redirect("auth/login");
        }
    }
    public function userdetails($user_id) {
        //load the User_model
        $this->load->model('User_model');

        //call function getdata in de Product_model
        $data['userdata_list'] = $this->User_model->getdata();

        //get product details
        $data['user'] = $this->User_model->get_user_info($user_id);

        //laad view
        $data['main_content'] = 'profiel_user';
        $this->load->view('profiel_user', $data);
    }
    public function profile() {
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        if ($_SESSION['user_logged'] == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "Please login first to view this page!! ");
            redirect("auth/login");
        }
        $this->load->view('profile');
    }
}
?>
```

And here is my model (User_model.php) :

```
<?php



public function getdata()
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
    $this->db->from('users');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
       return $query->result_array();
    }
}
public function getUserInfo($user_id) {
    $q = $this->db->get_where('users', array('user_id' => $user_id), 1);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $q->row();
        return $row;
    } else {
        error_log('no user found getUserInfo(' . $user_id . ')');
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Database information:

```
I have 2 tables:
 users:
user_id
voornaam
achternaam
email
password


(products:
product_id
product_name
product_description)
```

I hope someone can help me,
Thanks!

Comment: Please post your full controller function and view file.

Comment: Okay sir I edited my answer and added my whole controller and view file

Comment: @lablanco have you checked my answer below?

Comment: Please post your error message in view file.

Comment: There is no error message, The link on the view page is not working, its supposed to link to another profile page.

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating user name in anchor tag `herf` separate it and write between `<a>` and `</a>`
change your code as below:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'User/profiel_user?id='.$row['user_id']?>"><?=$row['username']; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Hello sir, I guess I'm 1 step further, I do see a link now but its a white blank box with a red stripe around it, and no username is being echoed and the link is not working either

Comment: What do you mean? i replaced it with your code you just posted

Comment: ok. You also have given table information in question. there is no `username` field in `users` table

Comment: Hello, I edited my answer and added my add data function in model,

Comment: And voornaam means username in the dutch language, I just translated it for you guys so you could see what I mean with the username field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155507/discussion-between-b-desai-and-lablanco).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem.

Please change your view file.

> details.php

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>User/profiel_user/'<?php $row['user_id'] ?>"><?= $row['username']; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

and please changes your controller function:

> User.php

```
<?php 
 public function profiel_user($user_id) {
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        if ($_SESSION['user_logged'] == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "Please login first to view this page!! ");
            redirect("auth/login");
        }
        $data['user_id'] = $user_id; // you can used user id for getting data
        $this->load->view('profile');
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: OK ill try, so you basiccally added new function called profiel_user in the controller right?

Comment: not working, also link is wrong on view page i want it too link to user profile while using user ID